# Is there any way to see all the indexed terms in a Mongodb text index?

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

I'm trying to make my mongodb collection searchable. I'm able to do text search after indexing a collection by text

```
db.products.createIndex({title: 'text'})
```

**I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve a list of all the index terms for this collection.** This would be very useful for auto completion and spell checking/correction when people are writing their search queries.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function for this in MongoDB. However, you can easily get this info with an aggregation query.

Let's assume that your collection contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874dbb1a1b342232b822827"), "title" : "title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874dbb8a1b342232b822828"), "title" : "new title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874dbbea1b342232b822829"), "title" : "hello world" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874dbc6a1b342232b82282a"), "title" : "world title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874dbcaa1b342232b82282b"), "title" : "world meta" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874dbcea1b342232b82282c"), "title" : "world meta title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874de7fa1b342232b82282e"), "title" : "something else" }
```

this query will give us the info on words :

```
db.products.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
         words:{
            $split:["$title"," "]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $unwind:"$words"
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$words",
         count:{
            $sum:1
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $sort:{
         count:-1
      }
   }
])
```

This output the number of occurence for each word :

```
{ "_id" : "title", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "world", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "meta", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "else", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "something", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "new", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "hello", "count" : 1 }
```

If you are using MongoDB 3.4, you can get case insensitive / diacritic insensitive stats on the words with the new [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) option.

for example, let's assume that our collection now contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874e057a1b342232b82282f"), "title" : "title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874e05ea1b342232b822830"), "title" : "new Title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874e067a1b342232b822831"), "title" : "hello world" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874e076a1b342232b822832"), "title" : "World Title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874e085a1b342232b822833"), "title" : "World méta" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874e08ea1b342232b822834"), "title" : "World meta title" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874e0aea1b342232b822835"), "title" : "something else" }
```

add the collation option to the aggregation query :

```
db.products.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
         words:{
            $split:["$title"," "]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $unwind:"$words"
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$words",
         count:{
            $sum:1
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $sort:{
         count:-1
      }
   }
],
{
   collation:{
      locale:"en_US",
      strength:1
   }
})
```

this will output:

```
{ "_id" : "title", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "world", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "méta", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "else", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "something", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "new", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "hello", "count" : 1 }
```

The strengh is the level of comparison to perform :

```
 collation.strength: 1 // case insensitive + diacritic insensitive
 collation.strength: 2 // case insensitive only
```

Comment: Thank you very much @felix. This is a great answer and helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose **autoCompleteTerm** is your input value you can get the list of title using this query:

```
db.products.distinct('title', { $text: { $search: autoCompleteTerm } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `db.products.distinct("title")` ,  what you are looking for ?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm looking for the terms that are searchable after mongodb has made an index of the titles, which is a set of distinct words found among the title fields of all products, each term somehow pointing to a list of products whose title contains this.  
Thank you for the reply anyway, that function might also be useful.